# How can i get all models in django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.8

I am using this code in my `admin.py`

```
from django.db.models import get_models, get_app

for model in get_models(get_app('myapp')):
    admin.site.register(model)
```

But i get warning that `get_models is deprecated`

How can i do that in django 1.8

Comment: It's a warning.  Is it actively *prohibiting* you from getting the models result?  I wouldn't expect a warning to do that except to inform you that this approach is going away in a future Django version.

Comment: @Makoto it says that it will be removed in 1.9 . i thought it would be better to use the latest stuff rather than chnage it in few months again

Comment: This is a totally rational reason to want to migrate; however, the way your question reads is that you were having trouble getting the values back from this command.  My concern was that it was prohibiting you from getting any information back, which would have been counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This should work,

```
from django.apps import apps
apps.get_models()
```

The `get_models` method returns a list of all installed models. You can also pass three keyword arguments `include_auto_created`, `include_deferred` and `include_swapped`.

If you want to get the models for a specific app, you can do something like this.

```
from django.apps import apps
myapp = apps.get_app_config('myapp')
myapp.models
```

This will return an OrderedDict instance of the models for that app.

Comment: I tried that  to register admin site like `admin.site.register(myapp.models[0])` but i get this `'str' object has no attribute '_meta'`

Comment: It's because it returns an `OrderedDict` instance. You want to call `myapp.models.values()`.