# Retrieving the Model object using table name

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to retrieve the `Model` object while knowing the table_name

For ex:

```
class User(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_users_table'
```

Are there ways that return `User` by taking `my_users_table` as input?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I would like to retrieve the `Model` object

I think you mean the Model class here instead of object.

One possible solution that I can think of is to get all the models and match for `db_table`:

```
from django.apps import apps
model = next((m for m in apps.get_models() if m._meta.db_table=='my_users_table'), None)
```

If there is no model with the given db_table name then the `model` will be `None`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a direct way to do this. But you can create your own function which will do this for you.

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/29739109/3627387

```
from django.apps import apps

def get_model_by_db_table(db_table):
    for model in apps.get_models():
        if model._meta.db_table == db_table:
            return model
    else:
        # here you can do fallback logic if no model with db_table found
        raise ValueError('No model found with db_table {}!'.format(db_table))
        # or return None
```

Or you can do this using [ContentType](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) model

*Edit:*

The link provided for **ContentType** is broken. [This may be tried instead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).