# Get the name of the classes I defined in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to get the names of the classes I defined in my models.py file. The closest I could get is to recover all the models in the application:

```
modelsList = django.apps.apps.get_models (include_auto_created=False)`
```

which gives:

```
<class 'django.contrib.admin.models.LogEntry'>
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Permission'>
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Group'>
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>
<class 'django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType'>
<class 'django.contrib.sessions.models.Session'>
<class 'app.models.Project'>
<class 'app.models.User'>
<class 'app.models.File'>
```

But I wanted only the string 'Project', 'User', 'File'. Is there anyway I can get that?

Comment: Iterate over those classes, access the `__name__` attribute.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [a answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738976/how-can-i-get-all-models-in-django-1-8):

```
from django.apps import apps

def get_models(app_name):
    myapp = apps.get_app_config(app_name)
    return myapp.models.values()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfect!

Answer (score 3):

You can get the model name for a model `Model` with `Model._meta.object_name`. So you could do something like:

```
import django.apps
models = django.apps.apps.get_models(include_auto_created=False)
model_names = [m._meta.object_name for m in models]
```