# Django: apps.get_models() yields models from unittests

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.10

If I call this django method, in a test, it yields a lot of models which are not installed.
These models are from other apps test code.

For example, when iI use `apps.get_models()` I get `MROBase1` from the django package polymorphic test code.

**=>** I want get all models which have a table in the database. In above question I got a model which exists just for testing, which is not on the database.

**NB:** I use Django 1.10

Comment: After the clarification provided at @Anupam 's answer, I have edited my answer accordingly. Have a look and please try toe dit your answer, as to be more clear about your intentions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to isolate the models from your application(s):

1. Create manually, a list of all your application names as strings: `my_apps=['my_app_1', 'my_app_2', ...]`
2. **(First Option)**, use `get_app_config` and `get_models` methods:

   ```
   from django.apps import apps

   my_app_models = {
       name: list(apps.get_app_config(name).get_models()) for name in my_apps
   }
   ```

   You will end up with a dictionary of `'app_name': list_of_models`
3. **(Second Option)**, use `all_models[<app_name>]` attribute:

   ```
   from django.apps import apps

   my_app_models = {name: apps.all_models[name] for name in my_apps}
   ```

   You will end up with a dictionary of `'app_name': OrderedDict_of_models`

Comment: I don't have the initial list of my_app. Can I use settings.INSTALLED_APPS for this?

Comment: @guettli Yes you could use INSTALLED_APPS but you may get third party models on your list if they are installed in there.

Comment: I want get all models which have a table in the database. In above question I got a model which exists just for testing, which is not on the database.

Comment: @guettli Is it on your installed apps?

Comment: please wait a second I check the question again ......... I read "These models are from other apps test code.". With other words the app polymorphic is in INSTALLED_APPS, but the models from the test code are not in the normal DB. That's what the question is a about: Why do models from test cases get returned if I call apps.get_models().

Comment: @guettli Because at the moment of the test, a test_db get's created and migrations applied to it. In this test_db the test code models are applied: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database. Finally, you can get your app names, by writing down your app folder names (they should be the same as your app names if you didn't do a massive manual change...). I can add this to the answer if this is what you are asking.

Comment: @JohnMoutafis I tried this approach but it gave me `<class 'tasks.models.Task'> is not JSON serializable` error

Comment: @Nitish without a complete view of your code I cannot help you. If you have a persistent problem, consider creating a new question with details.

Comment: @JohnMoutafis kindly refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390257/apps-get-models-only-custom-models

Answer (score 2):

`apps.get_models()` will return all installed models, if you want to restrict the set of installed apps used by get_app_config[s] you can use [set_available_apps](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/apps/registry.py#L290):

```
from django.apps import apps
myapp = apps.set_available_apps(list_of_available_apps)
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738976/how-can-i-get-all-models-in-django-1-8) SO post.

`apps.get_models()` will return all installed models. If you are looking for a list of models for a specific app, do the following:

```
from django.apps import apps
myapp = apps.get_app_config('myapp')
myapp.models #returns an OrderedDict
```

Also, for reference, [here's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/apps/config/#AppConfig.get_models) the source of `get_models()` to see how it works

Comment: Thank you for your question. But I think it does not fit to the question.

Comment: why? what else do you want?

Comment: I want to list all models of all apps. I don't have "myapp".